# Can I implement a breadcrumb trail using dijit.layout.StackContainer in Dojo? Are there better ways?

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I want to implement a breadcrumb trail in a website using Dojo - and I am considering using StackContainer.

Is this a good approach? Are there better ways of achieving the same thing?

--UPDATE--

Here is an article from IBM that makes use of the StackContainer for a breadcrumb trail

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-custom20/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but it takes a little work - see original link